# Como capturar elementos em uma estrutura json usando javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loop

Preciso pegar alguns elementos dentro de uma estrutura JSON com Javascript. Consigo pegar elementos unitários assim:

```
alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.MASTERCARD.images.SMALL.path);
alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.VISA.images.SMALL.path);
```

Mas preciso fazer um laço para capturar TODOS esses "path" (SMALL) de TODOS os tipos de cartões. Tentei de diversas formas mas sempre me retornam erro ou *undefined*.

Inclusive segui os passos [deste site](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it) que seria justamente o que preciso, mas sem sucesso.

**Javascript**:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
    success: function(response) {
        //meios de pagamento disponíveis 
    },
    error: function(response) {
        //tratamento do erro 
    },
    complete: function(response) {
        //tratamento comum para todas chamadas 
    }
});
```

**JSON**:

```
{
    "error":false,
    "paymentMethods":{
        "BOLETO":{
            "name":"BOLETO",
            "options":{
                "BOLETO":{
                    "name":"BOLETO",
                    "displayName":"Boleto",
                    "status":"AVAILABLE",
                    "code":202,
                    "images":{
                        "SMALL":{
                            "size":"SMALL",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/booklet.png"
                        },
                        "MEDIUM":{
                            "size":"MEDIUM",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/booklet.png"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "code":2
        },
        "ONLINE_DEBIT":{
            "name":"ONLINE_DEBIT",
            "options":{
                "BANCO_BRASIL":{
                    "name":"BANCO_BRASIL",
                    "displayName":"Banco do Brasil",
                    "status":"AVAILABLE",
                    "code":304,
                    "images":{
                        "SMALL":{
                            "size":"SMALL",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/bb.png"
                        },
                        "MEDIUM":{
                            "size":"MEDIUM",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/bb.png"
                        }
                    }
                },

            },
            "code":3
        },
        "CREDIT_CARD":{
            "name":"CREDIT_CARD",
            "options":{
                "MASTERCARD":{
                    "name":"MASTERCARD",
                    "displayName":"MasterCard",
                    "status":"AVAILABLE",
                    "code":102,
                    "images":{
                        "SMALL":{
                            "size":"SMALL",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/mastercard.png"
                        },
                        "MEDIUM":{
                            "size":"MEDIUM",
                            "path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/mastercard.png"
                        }
                    }
                },

            },
            "code":1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse json está mal formado.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal, infelizmente é como q esta no manual do pagseguro :(  

Alguma sugestao?

Comment: tenho sim. vou fazer aqui e te mando. pera só uns minutos.

Comment: tem que pegar todos as imagens small inclusive de boleto e Banco do Brasil? ou somente do dredit card?

Comment: só do CREDIT_CARD

Comment: Se quiser posso passar o resto do codigo p vc testar na pratica.

Comment: @A.A.F. para iterares todos os cartões esse JSON precisava de ter uma array para os cartões e não tem... Dá para encotrar o JSON completo, pelo menos com mais do que 1 cartão? Assim como está vamos estar a adivinhar.

Comment: @Sergio, Nao sei se isso ajuda mas consigo pegar 2 "path" chamando diretamente: alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.VISA.images.SMALL.path);
alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.MASTERCARD.images.SMALL.path);

Comment: @A.A.F. ok, nesse caso o JSON falta essa informação e não daria para saber do JSON somente. Ok, vou colocar uma resposta para você testar.

Comment: @A.A.F: tinha dado um problema na exibição da minha solução mas agora está ok. testa ai

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal sua solucao esta funcionando p um cartao mas quando vem mais de um da erro.

Comment: @A.A.F. Não funciona porque o json que o pagseguro colocou está incompleto. vc está pegando o json do webservice? olha lá. adicionei mais um cartao e funcionou. passa o json completo do webservice.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal, vc esta certissimo. Testei e funcionou bem. Agora só n sei como faco p aceitar duas respostas corretas. A sua e a do Sergio.

Comment: Esquenta não @A.A.F. Só em ajudar já é maior alegria. Abraço

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se consegues obter estes alerts ([como indicaste em nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45801/como-capturar-elementos-em-uma-estrutura-json-usando-javascript/45817#comment91898_45801)):

```
alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.VISA.images.SMALL.path);
alert(response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.MASTERCARD.images.SMALL.path);
```

Então quer dizer que `response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options` é um objeto com chaves para cada cartão. Nesse cado dá para iterar assim:

```
var cartoes = response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options;
var caminhos = Object.keys(cartoes).map(function(cartao){
    return {
        tipo: cartao,
        path: cartoes[cartao].images.SMALL.path
    };
});
```

Desta maneira vais ter uma array na variável `caminhos` onde cada elemento da array é um objeto com tipo do cartão e a path.

Se quiseres somente iterar os cartões podes usar:

```
Object.keys(cartoes).forEach(function(cartao){
    var path = cartoes[cartao].images.SMALL.path;
    // fazer algo com path
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um arquivo .html em anexo com o que eu acho que você está querendo fazer. Verfique por favor se é isso. Segue o código do html abaixo. É só copiar, salvar como html e testar no seu navegador.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bandeiras">

</div>
<script>
    var jsonText = '{ ' +
                '"error":false, ' +
                '"paymentMethods":{ ' +
                '"BOLETO":{ ' +
                '"name":"BOLETO", ' +
                '"options":{ ' +
                '"BOLETO":{ ' +
                '"name":"BOLETO", ' +
                '"displayName":"Boleto", ' +
                '"status":"AVAILABLE", ' +
                '"code":202, ' +
                '"images":{ ' +
                '"SMALL":{ ' +
                '"size":"SMALL", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/booklet.png" ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"MEDIUM":{ ' +
                '"size":"MEDIUM", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/booklet.png" ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"code":2 ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"ONLINE_DEBIT":{ ' +
                '"name":"ONLINE_DEBIT", ' +
                '"options":{ ' +
                '"BANCO_BRASIL":{ ' +
                '"name":"BANCO_BRASIL", ' +
                '"displayName":"Banco do Brasil", ' +
                '"status":"AVAILABLE", ' +
                '"code":304, ' +
                '"images":{ ' +
                '"SMALL":{ ' +
                '"size":"SMALL", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/bb.png" ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"MEDIUM":{ ' +
                '"size":"MEDIUM", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/bb.png" ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"code":3 ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"CREDIT_CARD":{ ' +
                '"name":"CREDIT_CARD", ' +
                '"options":{ ' +
                '"MASTERCARD":{ ' +
                '"name":"MASTERCARD", ' +
                '"displayName":"MasterCard", ' +
                '"status":"AVAILABLE", ' +
                '"code":102, ' +
                '"images":{ ' +
                '"SMALL":{ ' +
                '"size":"SMALL", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/mastercard.png" ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"MEDIUM":{ ' +
                '"size":"MEDIUM", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/mastercard.png" ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"VISA":{ ' +
                '"name":"VISA", ' +
                '"displayName":"MasterCard", ' +
                '"status":"AVAILABLE", ' +
                '"code":102, ' +
                '"images":{ ' +
                '"SMALL":{ ' +
                '"size":"SMALL", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/42x20/visa.png" ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"MEDIUM":{ ' +
                '"size":"MEDIUM", ' +
                '"path":"/public/img/payment-methods-flags/68x30/visa.png" ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '}, ' +
                '"code":1 ' +
                '} ' +
                '} ' +
                '}';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    $("#bandeiras").append('<h1>bandeiras</h1>');
    $.each(jsonObj.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options, function (index, value) {
        console.log(this.images.SMALL.path);
        $("#bandeiras").append('<img src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br' + this.images.SMALL.path + '">');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de deixa uma contribuição também, já utilizei essa api, minha solução foi assim,

```
var cartoes = response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options;
var i;
for(i in cartoes){
  if(cartoes.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      console.log(cartoes[i].images.SMALL.path);
  }
}
```

lembrando que esse método, é compatível com o IE8  e versões inferiores , já a função Object.keys não é.

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi direito, o problema seu é no trecho do "CREDIT_CARD", "MASTERCARD" e "SMALL", certo? Se for isso, o que você precisa é usar o laço "for-in" para percorrer as chaves de um objeto

```
 // Esse código imprime "a", "b" e "c", não necessariamente nessa ordem
 var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
 for(var k in obj){
     if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.apply(obj, k){
         console.log(k);
     }
 }
```

No seu caso:

```
var payment = response.paymentMethods;
for(var ptype in payment){
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(payment, ptype)){
        var options = payment[ptype].options;
        for(var otype in options){
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(options, otype)){
                var images = options[otype].images;
                for(var size in images){
                    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(images, size)){
                        var path = images[size].path;
                        console.log(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola @hugomg, queria percorrer todo o JSON. Na verdade o q preciso é só dos valores q estao em _paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.**NOMEDOCARTAO**.images.SMALL.path_
Existem vários cartoes (em NOMEDOCARTAO).